# Incompatible file format error message with Zend Optimizer 3.3.9

Tags: php, zend-optimizer, zend-guard

On my local machine, I'm trying to deploy PHP code which was obfuscated using Zend Guard under the PHP 5.2.10 engine.

Since my machine had PHP 5.3, I reckoned the code does not run since it was obfuscated using Zend guard under the older PHP engine.

I managed to downgrade my PHP engine to 5.2.10, and also configured php.ini to use the relevant .so file from ZendOptimizer-3.3.9-linux-glibc23-i386.

However, when I try to run my website, I get the following error message:

`Fatal error: Incompatible file format: The encoded file has format major ID 0, whereas the Optimizer expects 2 in /var/www/mysite/index.php on line 0`

What could I be missing out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the index.php file was corrupt.

I replaced it with the correct file and then received the message "Invalid license."

I finally had to add a line in the hosts file to resolve the server's domain to localhost, since the Zend license is valid only for particular domains.